# Prove that if $f$ is locally lipschitz of order $\alpha >0$ at $x_0$, then $ f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

We say a function is locally Lipstchitz of order $\alpha$ at $x_0$ if there exists $\epsilon, M>0$ such that

$$
|x-x_0|<\epsilon \rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<M(x-x_0)^\alpha
$$

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

I think that I just need to prove that $x^\alpha$ is continuous for all $\alpha>0$ and then the result follows by squeezing, but this turned out to be a bit complicated (the result is pretty obvious for $\alpha\in \Bbb N$). Is there an easier way?

I've read two similar questions here, but they used a different definition (without the $\epsilon$ part).

Also, what's an easy way to prove that if $\alpha>1$, then $f'(x_0)$ exists and it's equal to $0$?

E: This question is trivial if we assume various properties of the function $t\mapsto t^\alpha$, however, I want to prove this without assuming extra stuff (as that it is continous, or increasing, or differentiable, etc), if you use any of these things, I'd like you to post a proof.

Comment: if $x\to x_0$ then $|x-x_0|^\alpha\to 0$ so $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\to 0$. If $\alpha >1$ then $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\right |\leq M|x-x_0|^{\alpha -1}\to 0$ when $x\to x_0$

Comment: @Svetoslav Well, the "if $x\to x_0$ then $|x-x_0|^\alpha\to 0$" is what I meant by "proving $x^\alpha$ is continuous".

Comment: If you want to be pedantic about $t^\alpha$, then how exactly have you defined it? Any reasonable definition (e.g. $t^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha\log t}$) should quickly imply that it's an increasing function.

Comment: Yes, that definition should work, together with $e^x:=\sum_n \frac {x^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is some $\eta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\eta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq M|x-x_0|^{\alpha}$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $0<\delta<\min\{(\frac{\varepsilon}{M})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}},\eta\}$. If $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then
$$ |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq M|x-x_0|^\alpha<M\delta^{\alpha}<\varepsilon$$
which shows that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see why the inequality $$M|x-x_0|^\alpha<M\delta^\alpha$$ holds. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies that $|x-x_0|^\alpha<\delta^\alpha$ because $t\mapsto t^{\alpha}$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You  can just use upper limit to do it.
Since
$$
\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant \varlimsup_{n\to\infty}M(x-x_0)^\alpha=0
$$
We have
$$
\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0
$$
And so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0\quad\text{}\quad 
$$
For derivative, it is similar
$$
\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|}\leqslant \varlimsup_{n\to\infty}M(x-x_0)^{\alpha-1}=0
$$

Comment: There's no $n$ in any of the expressions you posted... As I've asked the others, how do you know that $\lim M(x-x_0)^\alpha = 0$?

Comment: You can use the fact that $x^{\alpha}$ is continuous at $0$, and it is obvious that $0^{\alpha}=0$. If you want to use $\epsilon-\delta$, you can take $\log$. But normally you don't have to do that.

Comment: Well, that's the point of my question (I said it comes down to showing $x^\alpha$ is continuous, but I didn't know how to prove it).